# Why are the following types of matrices reflections

Tags: linear-algebra, reflection

I'm curious why a linear operator T on R$^2$ is a reflection if it has orthogonal eigenvectors v$_1$ and v$_2$ with eigenvalues 1 and -1.

I'm hoping someone could show me a linear transformation that has eigenvectors with eigenvalues +1 and -1 but please choose a reflection other than just over the x-axis or y-axis. A reflection about some line would be great (the line should be one eigenvector from my understanding). I propose the orthogonal vectors [1,2] and [2,-1]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a specific notion of "reflection" in mind? What properties must an operator have in order for you to consider it a "reflection"?

Comment: hopefully this isnt excessively simple: a refelction in the standard basis would be [x,y] -> [x,-y], ie a flip over the vector e1. if i picked another orthogonal pair of vectors like e1 and e2, then a reflection would act the same way if u "tilt the axis". Does that make sense? this is all in R$^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your comment, your own concept of a reflection seems to be an image similar to reflecting in the $x$ or $y$ axis, but somehow the picture is rotated so that the axis in question becomes some arbitrary line. This is something we can work with.

We'll need the idea of an orthogonal operator. An operator $U$ is orthogonal if
$$(Ux) \cdot (Uy) = x \cdot y$$
for all $x, y \in \Bbb{R}^2$. In particular, note that
$$\|Ux\|^2 = (Ux) \cdot (Ux) = x \cdot x = \|x\|^2,$$
hence $U$ preserves distances. We can also recover the angle between vectors using the dot product, hence $U$ must also preserve angles. This means that the orthogonal operators are essentially just rotations and reflections. So, if you're thinking about rotating a picture so that one axis becomes an arbitrary line, orthogonal operators are what you need.

It also follows that orthogonal operators must be injective, since
$$U(x) = 0 \implies \|U(x)\| = 0 \implies \|x\| = 0 \implies x = 0.$$
Since $U$ is an injective operator on a finite-dimensional space, this implies $U$ is invertible. Inverses of orthogonal operators are also orthogonal, as
$$(U^{-1} x) \cdot (U^{-1} y) = (U(U^{-1} x)) \cdot (U(U^{-1}y)) = x \cdot y.$$

Now, let's normalise the eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. Let
$$u_i = \frac{v_i}{\|v_i\|}.$$
Then $u_1$ is a unit eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $1$, and similarly for $u_2$ with $-1$. Note that $u_1 \perp u_2$, and hence they form an orthonormal basis.

Consider the unique linear map $U$ taking $(1, 0)$ to $u_1$, and $(0, 1)$ to $u_2$. I claim that $U$ is an orthogonal operator. Given any $(a, b), (c, d) \in \Bbb{R}^2$,
\begin{align*}
U(a, b) \cdot U(c, d) &= U(a(1, 0) + b(0, 1)) \cdot U(c(1, 0) + d(0, 1)) \\
&= (aU(1, 0) + bU(0, 1)) \cdot (cU(1, 0) + dU(0, 1)) \\
&= (au_1 + bu_2) \cdot (cu_1 + du_2) \\
&= ac(u_1 \cdot u_1) + ad(u_1 \cdot u_2) + bc(u_2 \cdot u_1) + bd(u_2 \cdot u_2) \\
&= ac + 0 + 0 + bd \\
&= (a, b)\cdot(c,d).
\end{align*}

Let $R$ be the reflection in the $x$-axis, i.e. $R(x, y) = (x, -y)$. Let us follow, intuitively speaking, the composition
$$U R U^{-1}.$$
First, what does $U^{-1}$ do? Remember, it is an orthogonal operator, and will be some kind of reflection/rotation, preserving distances and angles. Note that $U$ maps the $x$-axis (i.e. $\operatorname{span}(1, 0)$) to the line spanned by $u_1$, i.e. the eigenspace of $T$ corresponding to $1$. Also, $U^{-1}$ maps the $y$-axis to the eigenspace of $T$ corresponding to $-1$. Hence, $U^{-1}$ will do the opposite: it will map $\operatorname{span}(u_1) \mapsto \operatorname{span}(1, 0)$ and $\operatorname{span}(u_2) \mapsto \operatorname{span}(0, 1)$.

So, when we apply $U R U^{-1}$, we apply $U^{-1}$ first, rotating the whole picture so that the eigenspace corresponding to $1$ maps to the $x$-axis, and the eigenspace corresponding to $-1$ maps to the $y$-axis. Then, $R$ is applied, leaving the $x$-axis fixed, but flipping the sign of the $y$-coordinate; i.e. the actual reflection has taken place. Finally, we apply $U$, undoing the effects of $U^{-1}$. The now reflected vector is rotated back, nullifying the change in perspective effected by $U^{-1}$.

In total, $U R U^{-1}$ has reflected the vector in the line $\operatorname{span}(v_1)$.

Now, it's not hard to see that this operator is indeed $T$. In fact, if you simply show that these linear operators agree on a basis, then they agree everywhere. The most sensible basis is $(u_1, u_2)$, the orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. By definition of eigenvectors, we have
\begin{align*}
T(u_1) = 1u_1 = u_1 \\
T(u_2) = (-1)u_2 = -u_2.
\end{align*}
On the other hand, we have
\begin{align*}
URU^{-1}(u_1) = UR(1, 0) = U(1, 0) = u_1 \\
URU^{-1}(u_2) = UR(0, 1) = U(0, -1) = -u_2.
\end{align*}
Therefore, the two operators agree on a basis, so they are the same operator, i.e.
$$T = URU^{-1}.$$
Hopefully my arguments are sufficient to convince you that $URU^{-1}$ is a reflection in the way that you understand the word, and hence so is $T$.

Comment: This is a wonderful explanation, thank you very much. Only question is that I believe when you write "Also, U$^{-1}$ maps the -axis to the eigenspace of  corresponding to −1. " you mean $U$ not $U^{-1}$ ?

Comment: You're right, but I think the better thing to say was that $U^{-1}$ maps the eigenspace corresponding to $-1$, to the $y$-axis. That's the salient property here: $U^{-1}$ maps from our perspective of the slanted mirror line, to the horizontal mirror line.

Comment: right. If we chose U to be an isometry but not necessarily an orthogonal matrix, would this still work?

Comment: Sort of. One of the steps in my argument was that $T$ was linear and $URU^{-1}$ is linear, and both agree on a basis, hence they are equal. If $U$ were a non-linear isometry, then extra argument would be needed to show that $T = URU^{-1}$. As it turns out, isometries of normed linear spaces are necessarily affine transformations (in an inner product space, orthogonal transformations composed with translations), and so one could potentially make a more complicated argument from this with a non-linear $U$. But it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Theo's answer settles the general question. I'll look at the particular one. We want $$\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}\pmatrix{1&2\cr2&-1}=\pmatrix{1&-2\cr2&1}$$ as that matrix takes $(1,2)$ to $(1,2)$, and $(2,-1)$ to $-(2,-1)=(-2,1)$. We find an inverse: $$\pmatrix{1&2\cr2&-1}^{-1}={1\over5}\pmatrix{1&2\cr2&-1}$$ so $$\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}={1\over5}\pmatrix{1&-2\cr2&1}\pmatrix{1&2\cr2&-1}={1\over5}\pmatrix{-3&4\cr4&3\cr}$$

Comment: so uve found a matrix with those eigenvalues, but how can we know that your found matrix will flip any vector [x,y] over the line created by [1,2]?

Comment: It will take $u=(x,y)$ to $v=((-3x+4y)/5,(4x+3y)/5)$, so all you have to do is prove that the result of flipping $u$ over $(1,2)$ is $v$. Can you do that?

Comment: would i compute the vector that projects from (x,y) onto the line spanned by [1,2], call it M, then compute (x,y) + 2M? that would be the reflection which should equal v?

Comment: Not quite. If $M$ is the projection of $u$ onto $(1,2)$, and $v$ is the reflection, then $u+v=2M$, so $v=2M-u$.

Comment: I believe my equation is correct when M is drawn with origin starting at u?

Comment: Well, try it for some simple example, say, reflecting $(1,1)$ in the $x$-axis, and see which formula is right.

Comment: (1,1) -> (1,-1) = v and your M would be (1,0). This vector is not perpendicular to the x axis. My M would be (0,-1), as that is the vector starting at u going perpendicular to the x axis. Then my equation yields: (1,1) + (0,-2) = (1,-1) = v.

Comment: I thought you meant $M$ was to be the projection of $u$ onto $(1,2)$, but now it appears you mean it to be the projection of $u$ onto the perpendicular to $(1,2)$. If that's what you mean by $M$, then in the $(1,1)$ and $x$-axis case, how do you get $M=(0,-1)$, and not $M=(0,1)$? In short, I don't understand what you mean by $M$.

Comment: Are you still here, H_1317?

Comment: what i meant was take the point (x,y), draw a perpendicular to the line spanned by (1,2). That line you just drew should be doubled and end up at v. I chose (0,-1) cause im envisioning being able to take my vector (x,y) and add "tip to tail" (x,y) + 2M and get to v. M in that case with our simple example across the x axis would be (0,-1)

Comment: OK, so I think I understand what you mean by $M$. If you want to reflect vector $a$ across vector $b$, you project $a$ onto $b$, getting $c$, and then you define $M=c-a$ – it's what you have to add to $a$ to get $c$. Then the reflection is $d=a+2M=2c-a$. Good, that works. But, there's no need to compute $M$. If you have the projection $c$, just use the formula $2c-a$. Anyway, now that we understand each other, have I answered the question in the 2nd paragraph of your post?

Answer (score 0):

The quick description is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & - \cos \theta
\end{array}
\right)
$$

As in Gerrry's answer, when the elements of the matrix are rational, the angle $\theta$ will not be familiar, it will be $\arctan$ of something, possibly negating or adding an integer multiple of $\pi$